# OpenCV on beaglebone. pkg-config issues

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, beagleboard

So i am running ubuntu 13.04 on the sd card of my new beaglebone black. I am attempting to install opencv-2.4.2. I've got everything installed without errors but when i try to build and run a program

```
g++ 'pkg-config opencv --cflags' FILE.cpp -o FILE 'pkg-config opencv --libs'
```

I get the error:

```
pkg-config opencv --cflags: no such file or directory
pkg-config opencv --libs: no such file or directory
```

When I run pkg-config --libs opencv it gives me the correct directory (/usr/lib/   .so) with all my libraries and I have confirmed they are all actually there. pkg-config opencv --cflags gives -I/usr/include/opencv. Which also exists.

I have edited my bash.bashrc, opencv.pc, and opencv.conf files reflect these paths. They were /usr/local/lib but no libraries installed there.

I'm running out of ideas guys, any help or suggestions would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: switched to Ubuntu 12.04 and it worked just fine. just incase someone stumbles across this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be using backticks (`) instead of ' to substitute the output of pkg-config into the command line.

Comment: This should be comment rather then answer

Answer (score 0):

opencv-2.4.2 is provided in the angstrom distribution that comes with the BeagleBone Black.  One problem I found was that python-opencv is at 2.3 with angstrom, so if you want to do your development work in python you have to downgrade opencv to 2.3.